# Divergence of twice contravariant tensors

Tags: differential-geometry

In a precedent topic (which can be found here : [Relationship between divergence operators defined with respect to two different volume forms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998655/relationship-between-divergence-operators-defined-with-respect-to-two-different) ), I asked the question of the relationship between the divergence operator for vector fields defined according to two volume forms.

This begs for two follow-up questions concerning twice contravariant tensors :

- Is a volume form enough to define the divergence of a twice contravariant tensors, or is it necessary to have a full metric to do so ?
- What is the relationship between the divergence of a twice contravariant tensor defined according to two different volume forms / metrics ?

Comment: Someone ? Anyone ?

Comment: There might be a good reason why nobody answered this question: what do you understand by the divergence of a tensor field, in general? I have only encountered the concept of divergence of a vector field. Your question might be given a meaning on Euclidean spaces, but probably not on abstract smooth manifolds.